# OpenGL ES GL_TRIANGLES gradient issue

Tags: opengl-es, glkit

I am trying to draw a area graph with a gradient. This is what I have right now.

[image]

If you look at the red-green graph, you will notice the gradient is does not look the way its supposed to.

EDIT: The gradient should be uniform like this:

[image]

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKit to draw a bunch of charts. The chart is drawn using GL_TRIANGLES. I understand that the issue is that the gradient is being  drawn for each triangle individually.

The only approach I can think of is to use a stencil buffer. I will draw the gradient in a big rectangle and clip it to this shape using the stencil. Is there a better way to do this? If not could you help me draw a stencil with specified points? I am new to OpenGL and not getting a good explanation on using stencil buffer.

Comment: I don't notice that the gradient doesn't look the way it's supposed to because I don't know how it's supposed to look. We'll be better able to help if you clarify that.

Comment: @rickster: updated with an example image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a stencil buffer. I don't think more triangles will help, either — more likely that'd just cause you more confusion because you'd be assigning per-vertex colors to intermediate vertices and having to interpolate them yourself.

Your gradients are coming out that way because of how and where you assign vertex colors for interpolation. Notice the difference in colors between your output and the example of what you're looking for:

[image: same colors at all top vertices]
You've got 100% red at every vertex along the top edge of your graph, and 100% green at every vertex along the bottom edge. OpenGL interpolates colors linearly across the face of each triangle, which is why you've got more red in the shorter parts of your graph.

[image: different colors at all top vertices]
In the output you're looking for, the top of the graph starts out less red in the shorter parts, so that it makes a shorter transition to white in over shorter distance.

There are a few different ways to do this, but probably the easiest (for your plan of using `GLKBaseEffect` instead of writing your own shaders) might be to use a 1D texture for your gradient, and assign a texture coordinate to each vertex that's proportional to its Y coordinate on the graph, like so:

[image: proportional texture coordinates]

(The example coordinates in my diagram assume your graph vertices cover the range 0.0 to 1.0, but the point stands regardless: the vertical texture coordinate for each point should be a fraction of the graph's total height, between 0.0 and 1.0.)

Alternatively, you could look into drawing in two passes: First, draw the shape of your graph, then draw a quad (two triangles) covering the entire screen with your gradient, using the appropriate `glBlendFunc` so that it only draws over the area you've filled in with your graph shape.

Comment: Your explanation of the colour strength at various 'peaks' in the graph make perfect sense, thanks for the effort. I had an idea this might be the problem but imagined the solution would be something trivial, given my experience with Core Graphics. I will try to two solutions you suggest.

Comment: Ok got it working with the second approach. For anyone who tries this the blending function I used was: glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO);

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES can do what you want but you need to increase the tessellation of your model.  In other words, instead of using just a few large triangles, you need more and smaller triangles, with the vertex color changes spread over them evenly.  This will give you better control over the gradients.  Triangles are cheap on accelerated OpenGL ES, so even if you increase the number 100 times, it will not have much impact on performance.

You might also consider a different approach, where the entire graph is covered by a single texture which contains the gradient.  That would be easier to implement.

Comment: even if i divide the shape into smaller triangles, won't I still have the same problem of each small triangle being coloured individually?